# RegEx pattern to always uppercase "CA" and "USA" in address string

Tags: javascript, regex

```
end_address = 'joe place, 555 test street, sacramento, ca, usa 95814';

end_address = end_address.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
```

The final result of this is:

> Joe Place, 555 Test Street, Sacramento, Ca, Usa 95814

but my desired output is:

> Joe Place, 555 Test Street, Sacramento, CA, USA 95814

How can I match a string so that "`CA`" and "`USA`" are always uppercase like the desired output?

Comment: If you don't have a field specifically for state and country, you're going to have a hard time with this. What if I'm a Japanese rabbit store and I want my address to be "Usa Farm, 555 test street, sacramento, ca, usa 95814"? Which "usa" do you capitalize?

Comment: Is the address always going to be `state, country, zip`?

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```js
end_address = 'jOe place, 555 test street, sacramento, ca, usa 95814'.toLowerCase();

end_address = end_address.replace(/\b(usa\b|ca\b|\w)/g, function(txt) { return txt.toUpperCase(); });

alert(end_address);
```

First, I lowercase it all, then apply the capitalization regex, `/\b(usa\b|ca\b|\w)/g`, which looks for the start of a word. It will match, then capitalize "usa", "ca" or the first character of the word.

Comment: Why are you lowercasing it all? That seems inelegant, and not in line with the OP's goal.

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz It was not explicitly stated as a requirement, but the code indicates it is. If you look, the function uppercases the first letter and lowercases the rest of the string.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is something like this:

```
address = address.replace(
    /([a-z]{2}),\s*([a-z]{3})\s*(\d{5})$/i,
    function(match, state, country, zip) {
        return state.toUpperCase() + ", " + country.toUpperCase() + " " + zip;
    })
```

It'll do the replacement in one pass, and will only touch the state/country (assuming those are at the end of the string).

[See the regex work on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mT2aE6/2)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the pattern will always be the same, you need to do a second pass at the string.

```
var result = end_address
  .replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){
    return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
  }).replace(/(\w{2}), (\w+) (\d{5}(-\d{4})?)$/, function(match, state, country, zip) {
    return state.toUpperCase() + ", " + country.toUpperCase() + ", " + zip;
  });
```